# Execute Menu Item Shortcuts from Terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, shortcut

Is there a way to write a bash script that opens a program and then executes a menu shortcut of the program?

For example,

open XCode project -> Command + R to run

open Chrome -> Command + N for new window

I thought it might look something like:

`$ open MyProject.xcodeproj | exec ⌘ r`

Comment: As a general statement no, you can't do this. Some applications have ways of triggering application actions from outside (via script/etc.) but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps provide command line API which you can use to trigger the actions.

Instead that you can use Automator.app on OS X and use AppleScript for GUI scripting. Here is similar question like yours:

[AppleScript or Automator to click on menus in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111736/applescript-or-automator-to-click-on-menus-in-an-application)